# Why aren't my bind variables working in APEX 19?

Tags: oracle-apex, bind-variables

I've been using APEX ever since version 4, and I remember making Classic Reports with queries like "select b, c, d from my_table where a = :P1_A_VALUE"

:P1_A_VALUE might have been created on page 1 as a static value for page item P1_A_VALUE, with a value of say, 'shoes', always set regardless of session state.  So, in my report I would have retrieved the b, c, d records from my_table where a = 'shoes'.

When I do this in 19, the app server crashes with a 500 error, and the java crash report in the Tomcat logs is tremendous, though unhelpful.

If I write the query as "select b, c, d from my_table where a = 'shoes', it works fine.  If I can somehow write the where clause with a function somehow, like "where a = func(z)", where func(z) returns 'shoes', it also works fine.  Only if I use the bind variable :P1_A_VALUE in the query does it break.

Has the behavior of APEX changed in the last couple of releases?  I went from 5 to 19, so many things could have happened.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Did you try to **rename** the P1_A_VALUE to ... something else? Such as P1_LITTLEFOOT (doesn't really matter, just to be different from what you have now).

Comment: No, I set the value of P1_A_VALUE on page 1 and was using it on page six.  Kept the same name throughout.

Comment: Right; as I said, **try** to rename P1_A_VALUE to something else. Or leave it *as is*, but create a new P1_B_VALUE, set its value on page 1 and then use P1_B_VALUE (instead of P1_A_VALUE) on page six.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you.  But I tried what you suggested and it still blew up real good.  Interestingly, it's not all bind variables that cause problems, because if I write something like "select a, b, c, where d = function(:P1_A_VALUE)", it still works OK.  It's only if I put the bind variable directly in the SQL of the query.

It doesn't like them in a PL/SQL block either.  I wrote 
BEGIN
for vRec in (select b,c from my_table where a = :P1_A_VALUE) loop
    htp.p('b = '||vRec.b||'; c = '||vRec.c);
end loop;
END;

and got the same 500 error.  Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: No problem, formatting is the least of your problems. I was hoping that such a trivial action (renaming P1_A_VALUE) would help. Sometimes my pages *go wild* and there's no help; I have to delete it and create a new one from scratch, no differences at all (or I just think so) and the new page just *works*. Sorry, I don't have any other ideas. I hope someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks.  I put a service request into the Oracle help desk on Friday.  I'll post whatever solution they come up with here.  Interestingly though, I'm not having this problem on my Apex 19 at home.

Comment: And the end of all this is... I was looking at the wrong place in my query for the cause.  I thought it was the bind variable, but it was actually the structure of the WHERE clause.